# Create bindable property for ColumnDefinitionCollection in contenview Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a common ContentView which has been called in many ContentPages.
Different pages have different requirements, according to the requirement, I want to change ColumnDefinition width property.

For Example:

On one page, There are three controls inside the Grid view, and the widths are "*,1,*"

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,1,*">
```

but on the other pages, I want to turn off the visibility of the first two controls, that is why I want to assign a width to Auto for the first two controls.

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*">
```

In order to achieve this functionality, I have created bindable property.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty GridColumnDefinitionProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(GridColumnDefinition), typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection), typeof(PopupView), "*,1,*"); 

public ColumnDefinitionCollection GridColumnDefinition
        {
            get => (ColumnDefinitionCollection)GetValue(GridColumnDefinitionProperty);
            set => SetValue(GridColumnDefinitionProperty, value);
        }
```

but I am getting this error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Default value did not match return type.
> Property: Xamarin.Forms.ColumnDefinitionCollection
> PopupView.GridColumnDefinition Default value type: String, Parameter
> name: defaultValue'

I am getting this error at the Bindable property line.

Comment: you didn't post the error message

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Default value did not match return type. Property: Xamarin.Forms.ColumnDefinitionCollection PopupView.GridColumnDefinition Default value type: String, 
Parameter name: defaultValue'

I am getting this error at the Bindable property line.

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: you need to use `ColumnDefinitionCollectionTypeConverter`.  See https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/caab66bcf9614aca0c0805d560a34e176d196e17/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Grid.cs#L76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple situations, an alternative approach is to create the needed ColumnDefinitions in code behind. With a `bool` property controlling when to do so.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="theGrid" ... />
```

```
public static readonly BindableProperty UseAutoColumnsProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(UseAutoColumns), typeof(bool), typeof(ContentPage), false);
public bool UseAutoColumns
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(UseAutoColumnsProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(UseAutoColumnsProperty, value);

        if (value)
            theGrid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection
            {
                new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Auto),
                new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Auto),
                new ColumnDefinition(GridLength.Star),
            };
    }
}
```